# Term for functionality where cli text is scrolled one line with enter, page of lines with space, quit with Q?

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I would like to add the long help navigation functionality to my cli app. For example:

```
git config --list
```

... or ...

```
man ls
```

I'm looking for a ready-made node module, but I'm getting to the point of implementing it myself. Even then, I'd like to know what that functionality is called.

Thanks!

## Update

The closest I came to describing this is captured by the `more` command. Since folks can just pipe my output to more, I've decided not to spend a lot of time reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You will need a bunch of different libraries to achieve this in a clean manner. "interactive cli node.js" seems to provide good search results:
https://opensource.com/article/18/7/node-js-interactive-cli

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I came to describing this is captured by the `more` command. Since folks can just pipe my output to `more`, I've decided not to spend a lot of time reinventing the wheel.

```bash
my-amazing-app | more
```

FYI. In case someone else is looking for more google fodder.